# Select Box not dispalying similar in browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, checkbox, contact-form-7

I was working on a contact form for this site page [MY site page](http://constantin-entertainment.info/jdfinancial/applications-quick/) using Contact form 7 word press plugin. I have added a few checkboxes in order to get some info from the visitors. And, when I published the page, the check box was displaying line by line. So I added the below CSS to display it in each line:

```
.wpcf7-checkbox
{
   display:table-caption;
}
```

This one displayed the checkboxes in each line but when I opened it in Mozilla it is not showing the way I wanted. I don't know what happened. Someone, please help me do this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
span.wpcf7-list-item {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the site or a demo?

Comment: so instead you want s the checkboxes to be stacked on top of eachother?

Comment: yes .. in each linme .. like a line break after each options

Comment: span.wpcf7-list-item {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    display: block;
}

Comment: So I presume that fixed it?

Comment: it fixed but it affected the radio buttons also .. ineed it for only select checkboxes

Comment: Before you attempted this you should have had a handle on what you are doing. What I have suggested targets everything because they are all in the same box. you need to look at the css and perhaps create some new classes to target the checkboxes and to separate from the radios.